# How to overrides material-ui inbuilt classes

Tags: reactjs

```
.MuiFormGroup-root-201 {       
    display: flex;      
    flex-wrap: wrap;      
    flex-direction: column;      
}
```

How to override flex-direction property column to row?

Comment: use `!important` in your css to override it

Comment: Can you add more code or an example to reproduce the issue?

Comment: its not working @Thinker

Comment: as @Justcode said, can you briefly explain the issue with more code so that it will be easy for us to find a solution

Comment: I added radio button code ,i want to display the radio button in inline,  @Justcode

Comment: i added some css code bt not working

Comment: @ajulaanandh show use html code

Comment: @ajulaanandh So you want to display radio button in a row, right? and how many radio buttons ar there?

Comment: i used material-ui  , so some inbuilt classes are working , how to i avoid this

Comment: yea i want to display radio button in row. there are 3 radio buttons @Thinker

Comment: <FormControl component="fieldset"><label>Gender</label>
          <RadioGroup
            aria-label="gender"
            name="gender2"
            className={classes.group}
            
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          >

Comment: <FormControlLabel
              value="female"
              control={<Radio color="primary" />}
              label="Female"
              labelPlacement="start"
            />
            <FormControlLabel
              value="male"
              control={<Radio color="primary" />}
              label="Male"
              labelPlacement="start"
            />

Comment: <FormControlLabel
              value="other"
              control={<Radio color="primary" />}
              label="Other"
              labelPlacement="start"
            />
          </RadioGroup>
          </FormControl>

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default theme:

App.tsx

```
import { createMuiTheme, MuiThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import themeConfig from "lib/material-ui/theme";

const theme = createMuiTheme(themeConfig);

class App extends PureComponent<IAppProps> {
public render() {
    return (
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        //..
```

lib/material-ui/theme.tsx

```
import overrides from "./overrides";
import typography from "./palette";

export default {
   palette,
   overrides,
};
```

./overrides.ts

```
export default {
    MuiFormGroup: {
        root: {
            display: "flex";
            flexWrap: "wrap";
            flexDirection: "row";
        },
    },
}
```